# Redirect all links containing # hash sign

Tags: vue.js, redirect, router, history

After changing Vue router mode from hash to history, old links do not redirect the user to the new URL.

Some still use the old link.

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/#/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
  ]
})
```

I need to redirect all existing URL links to URL without hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace hash in `beforeEach` hook:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.fullPath.substr(0,2) === "/#") {
    const path = to.fullPath.substr(2);
    next(path);
    return;
  }
  next();
});
```